# Pushing input value to data layer GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to push an input value from a form to the GTM data layer. I've read through a bunch of different guides and am still a bit confused by the necessary steps. Currently I've set-up the following:

1. Trigger that fires an html tag
2. Html tag that has some custom javascript to capture the input value (see below)

```js
<script>
  
    /* event listener */
    document.getElementsByName("UnitPrice")[0].addEventListener('change', doThing);
    
    /* function */
    function doThing(){
     var donateAmount = this.value;
      
      console.log(donateAmount);
     
      window.dataLayer.push({
          'event' : 'donation',
          'donationAmount' : donateAmount
        });
    } 
</script>
```

My question is two-fold. First, shouldn't I be seeing info pushed to the data layer (using GTM debugger) whenever an input is updated on that form item? Second, am I missing a step here as far as getting the data to the data layer?

Edit:

Below is the html for the input field

```
<input name="UnitPrice" type="hidden" id="UnitPrice" value="" />
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what steps you performed to integrate  GTM, before reaching to this question,

Comment: Can you please attach your HTML markup with your input

Comment: @SantoshKumar not sure if I follow the question? The GTM is set-up in the standard way on the website using Google's documentation

Comment: @VictorLeontyev just added in the HTML markup

Answer (score 0):

'change' is quite a tricky event. Usually, this event is not fired after text value was changed and waits for an input to lose focus. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

I suppose that you don't need that push for every input change but only for some "submit" interaction. You can use User-defined Variable of  Custom Javascript type to expose this value to GTM:

```
function () {
  return document.getElementsByName("UnitPrice")[0].value; 
}
```

and then access the value in your tags by referring the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on 'change' event -- just reviewed the doc and that makes a lot of sense. You're right about only needing it on submit, I'll give your idea a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Having trouble implementing this, just added in the code above, can you please point me in the right direction? Really appreciate all your help

Comment: 0. Check if function above works for you returning the correct value.
1. in GTM add a user-defined variable of Custom JavaScript type with the function as above
2. Preview your container. The value will be available in GTM with  'donation' event. Navigate to Variables tab in debug window to check